# pandas - add two dataframes together where values are the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of word counts, let's say the first is...

```
    word   count
0   HELLO  8
1   MORE   10
2   HELP   19
3   NO     100
```

and second is...

```
     word    count
0    HELLO   10
1    MORE    12
2    NONE    20
3    NO      56
```

The result should be...

```
     word    count
0    HELLO   18
1    MORE    22
2    HELP    19
2    NONE    20
3    NO      156
```

The order does not matter. But I must ensure that all words are preserved. If the word exists in both dataframes, we sum the count. If one does not exist in the other, we simply add it.

I figured out how to add two dataframes...

```
df_add = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

But this is all I know. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge the dataframes and sum,

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'word', how = 'outer')
new_df['count'] = new_df[['count_x', 'count_y']].sum(1)
new_df.drop(['count_x', 'count_y'], 1, inplace = True)

    word    count
0   HELLO   18.0
1   MORE    22.0
2   HELP    19.0
3   NO      156.0
4   NONE    20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use append and groupby to get the result using this one liner -

```
df_1.append(df_2).groupby('word', as_index=False).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, first `pandas.merge` the dataframes together. Then sum both `count` columns and finally use `fillna` to fill the `NaN`

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='word', how='outer', suffixes=['', '_2'])

df3['count'] = df3['count'].fillna(0) + df3['count_2'].fillna(0)
df3['count'].fillna(df3['count_2'], inplace=True)
df3.drop('count_2', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df3)
    word  count
0  HELLO   18.0
1   MORE   22.0
2   HELP   19.0
3     NO  156.0
4   NONE   20.0
```